# Compress photos in PhoneGap on IOS for XML generation

Tags: ios, xml, api, cordova, compression

I have an app which stores photos taken using phonegap camera plugin a sqllite db on app  running on IPad air 2. 
The photos are appended to an XML which is transferred to an API over web services

At any one point in time there maybe 100s  of photos to export and the xml generated with the base64 encoding is very large.

What would be the best way to compressing the images before the generation of the XML?

In the PhoneGap camera plugin there doesn't seem to be any parameters which will allow photo compression or change in resolution??

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
   destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
   quality : 50,
   encodingType : Camera.EncodingType.JPEG
   correctOrientation : true
});
```

Correct orientation property will Reduce the size of image.

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: Thank you! Will give that a try. I couldn't  find any info as to why the Correct Orientation would reduce the size of the image.

Comment: I couldn't find a way of changing the resolution/size before saving to the sqllite database with setting the targetwidth and target height. As th.e new ipad air 2 captures  by default the highest resolution. Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: I got file sizes of 4.5MB from an iPhone 5 after correct orientation it reduces to 400kb.